# Viewing org-journal entries

Tags: org-mode, calendar

I have installed [`org-journal`](https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal) and it seems to work well to create entries. However, I can't find and view them again. The [documentation on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgJournal) says to view the entry:

> In calendar view:
>
> - `j` to view an entry

I'm not sure what is meant by "calendar view". I exececute <kbd>M-x</kbd> `calendar` and the bottom of the screen has a 3-month calendar and the days that have journal entries are highlighted. I move the cursor over one of the highlighted dates and press <kbd>j</kbd>. I get an error about undefined key.

So, what exactly is meant by "calendar view"? Does `org-mode` have its own calendar view?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of [org-journal](https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal). As [Rusi pointed out](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10462/viewing-org-journal-entries#comment16084_10482), the problem is that Emacs 23 does not support `setq-local`. You can backport `setq-local` from Emacs 24 to 23, but you'll have to delete or recreate `org-journal.elc` for the backport to take effect.

Nevertheless, I have removed the dependence on `setq-local` in the latest version of org-journal. Org-journal is now compatible with Emacs 23.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

C-j does seem to work (for me).
And the README says there's a breaking change from j to C-j

[EDIT]

One or two more clarifications:

1. Both j and C-j work (in calendar) -- current version of org-journal
2. The date tracked by calendar is the date (encoded in) the file name not the date inside the file. So if my file contains "* Friday, 04/03/2015"
   but is itself having the name 20150402, then Thursday will be highlighted not Friday. IOW journal is not clever enough to detect/correct date-anomalies

Comment: Neither j nor C-j work for me.  And when you say '(in calendar)' do you mean  M-x calendar?

I did grab the version of org-journal from 2 days  ago off the Github site.

When I try j I get these errors:
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function setq-local)
      (setq-local org-hide-emphasis-markers t)
      (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (when (not had-a-buf) (view-mode)
     (setq view-exit-action ...)) (setq-local org-hide-emphasis-markers t)
        (org-show-subtree))

Comment: github shows the C-j change as 3 days ago. So pull again and try. Also need org-version, emacs version.

Comment: Emacs is 23.1.1      Org mode is 8.2.10   I reinstalled org-journal today.   No change in behavior.  Computer is gov't owned and not easy to update.   Anything installed is in my home directory.

Comment: setq-local introduced in 24.3. Try making this defn before load/require org-journal: (defmacro setq-local (var val)
  (list 'set (list 'make-local-variable (list 'quote var)) val))

Comment: Hopefully now if your problem is solved do undo the downvote :-)

Comment: I will try the macro.  Thanx.   I'm afraid I didn't do the downvote and don't know anything about it.

Comment: You'll have to delete any compiled version of org-journal (org-journal.elc) for the macro to take effect. Note that the latest version of org-journal should work without the macro.